Flutter error version with google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
In flutter i have this version: flutter: 3.22.3 • channel stable
Inmmy project i am using this version: google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0.
My `pubspeck.yaml`:

name: hbapp
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.2+2

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.4 <4.0.0'    

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0 #actual version

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

But when i run app flutter run this error appears:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
           Type io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: F:\projects\hubia2\build\webview_flutter_android\.transforms\59c60ff2c14b6cf9814c93048d213367\transformed\classes\classes.dex, F:\projects\hubia2\build\webview_pro_android\.transforms\9cf8db7253fc8e900f654f3e60e164e0\transformed\classes\classes.dex

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             37,8s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

This is my build.gradle (project level):
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'  
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

And this is my build.gradle (app level):
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.blogspot.hubiaapp"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hbaapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

The error only stops appearing when I downgrade to: google_mobile_ads: ^2.4.0. It compiles well and correctly.
Then, there is a relationship with the version of the google_mobile_ads package. How could we solve this?"

If you are using visual studio code then right click on android folder and select open with android studio, then try to run from there, the error report is better there.

it doesn't matter, the error is the same.
